# Error when restoring Postgres Database on RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws

I am following this to restore an externally backed up Postgres DB onto my RDS instance - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

However, when I try to restore I get the following errors -

```
CREATE EXTENSION
psql:database.sql:2615: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
CREATE EXTENSION
psql:database.sql:2629: ERROR:  must be owner of extension pg_trgm
```

I believe this has to do with assigning superuser privileges to the user. However, I know this is not possible to do in RDS. How can I workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are harmless and can be ignored.

They stem from `COMMENT ON EXTENSION` statements in the dump.